# NullReferenceException thrown when trying to update a XIB's child view in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, interface-builder, xamarin-studio

I'm testing Xamarin Studio and deploying with Xamarin.iOS. I'm just starting to learn how iOS apps behave and how to use its tools.

I've gotten the basics to create custom views with Xcode Interface Builder (IB) and how to display them on my storyboard created located in my project on Xamarin Studio.

Now what I'm trying to do is to update the content of a custom view based on user interaction over other components inside it.

For example, I have a custom view with a table view and an image view in it. Each row inside the table represents an image file path and when a row is selected then the corresponding image should be displayed into the image view.

I've implemented my own UITableViewSource class where I override the RowSelected method as follows:

```
    public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        var index = indexPath.Row;
        var item = tableItems [index];

        selectedFilePath = item;
        var array = GetFilePathArray (item);
        selectedFileName = GetFileName (array);
        // I should be using an interface but this is only a test
        ((SavedPhotosView)tableView.Superview).SetSelectedFile (selectedFileName, selectedFilePath);
    }

    protected string[] GetFilePathArray(string path){
        string[] separators = { "/" };
        return path.Split (separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    }

    protected string GetFileName(string[] pathArray){
        var arrayLength = pathArray.Length;
        return pathArray [arrayLength - 1];
    }
```

SavedPhotosView is the class I created to connect my SavedPhotosView.xib file to my project, the implementation I used is the following:

```
[Register("SavedPhotosView")]
public partial class SavedPhotosView : UIView
{
    public SavedPhotosView(IntPtr h): base(h){

    }

    public SavedPhotosView(){

        var arr = NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNib ("SavedPhotosView", this, null);
        var v = Runtime.GetNSObject (arr.ValueAt (0)) as UIView;
        v.Frame = new RectangleF (0, 0, Frame.Width, Frame.Height);

        // For some reason I can register the class for the cell here without receiving a null exception
        SavedPhotosTableView.RegisterClassForCellReuse (typeof(UITableViewCell), (NSString)SavedPhotosTableViewSource.cellIdentifier);

        AddSubview (v);
    }
    // Method used to update the source of the table view, null exception isn't thrown here
    public void SetSource(UITableViewSource source){
        InvokeOnMainThread (delegate {

            SavedPhotosTableView.Source = source;
            SavedPhotosTableView.ReloadData ();
        });
    }
    // Method that receives the file name and file path for the image to be displayed
    public void SetSelectedFile(string filename, string filepath){
        UIImage selectedImage = UIImage.FromFile (filepath);
        // Null reference exception is thrown here, also if I try to update something on the table view here I get a null reference exception too
        InvokeOnMainThread (delegate {
            SelectedSaveImageView.Image = selectedImage;
        });
    }
}
```

I don't understand what is causing this exception, when I update the source object for my table view I don't encounter any exceptions, but on my other method neither my table view or my image view can be referenced at all.

I created the outlets for both my table view and image view in IB so I was expecting to be able to reference them from my C# class with no problem.

Is my implementation wrong here? How can reference other elements in my custom view without worrying about having this kind of exception to be thrown?

**EDIT 1**

I noticed that when I call my SetSource method, I'm doing that call from my ViewController that displays my custom view.

So that means I can access to the outlets but only if the method is being called from inside my controller.

Unfortunately, when I tried to pass an instance of my ViewController into SavedPhotosView (the C# class that represents the binding the xib file with my Xamarin.iOS code as far as I understand), I debugged the application and indeed the reference is passed correctly when I create the instance of SavedPhotosView, but when my table view source handles the click event and tries to access to this View Controller instance the reference is null.

Why is my reference being nullified?

I tried with a static reference to my ViewController inside my SavedPhotosView but I don't like that workaround. It works but it is not my desired approach.

How can I get ride of this workaround? Or is this the only way to do this?

Stack trace:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at TestCustomViewsiOS.UI.Views.SavedPhotosView+<SetSelectedFile>c__AnonStorey1.<>m__0 () [0x00012] in /Users/xxxxxxxxx/Projects/TestCustomViewsiOS/TestCustomViewsiOS/UI/Views/SavedPhotosView.cs:41
  at MonoTouch.Foundation.NSActionDispatcher.Apply () [0x00000] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/maccore/src/Foundation/NSAction.cs:56
  at at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Messaging:void_objc_msgSend_IntPtr_IntPtr_bool (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,bool)
  at MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject.InvokeOnMainThread (MonoTouch.Foundation.NSAction action) [0x00007] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/maccore/src/Foundation/NSObject2.cs:506
  at TestCustomViewsiOS.UI.Views.SavedPhotosView.SetSelectedFile (System.String filename, System.String filepath) [0x00027] in /Users/xxxxxxxxxx/Projects/TestCustomViewsiOS/TestCustomViewsiOS/UI/Views/SavedPhotosView.cs:40
  at TestCustomViewsiOS.ApplicationLayer.DataSource.SavedPhotosTableViewSource.RowSelected (MonoTouch.UIKit.UITableView tableView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath) [0x00048] in /Users/xxxxxxxxxx/Projects/TestCustomViewsiOS/TestCustomViewsiOS/Application/DataSource/SavedPhotosTableViewSource.cs:64
  at at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, IntPtr principal, IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:62
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x00038] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:46
  at TestCustomViewsiOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00008] in /Users/xxxxxxxxxxxx/Projects/TestCustomViewsiOS/TestCustomViewsiOS/Main.cs:17
```

Comment: Where is the exception stack trace?

Comment: you can check it at [this link](http://pastebin.com/6GP2tAKe)

Comment: @HotLicks '// Null reference exception is thrown here...' I guess that block is line 41 -- that also fits with the stack trace (btw +1 to the question. it has more details than most)

Comment: I dont know enough c# or xamarin to tell you why the ref is nullified though

Comment: It is odd, if I make the call from the controller side then no problem with the references, but if I tried to call that method from my table source class that's when the reference is null. 
@HotLicks are the references only persistent from the controller side?

Comment: I don't know if the `InvokeOnMainThread` is async.  If so, then something in `SelectedSaveImageView.Image` could be going bye-bye in the interim.  (Though have you added code prior to the `Invoke...` to verify that the values are not null at that point??)

Comment: I yes, I tried both outside and inside an InvokeOnMainThread call. From what I understand in (this article)[http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/controls/part_2_-_working_with_the_ui_thread/] since I'm calling the method SetSelectedFile from an event callback then the InvokeOnMainThread call is required.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your situation, but I most often get this error when I have forgotten to connect an object in Interface Builder with its reference point in the file object.

Comment: I have both the table view and the image view connected to their respective outlets, [here is a screenshot of my .h file](http://i.imgur.com/aKzoHjD.png). I've reduced this to making the call from the controller, but I don't find a good practice in passing around a reference for the controller.

Comment: The connection I was thinking of is stored in the xib file, and so represented by a dot beside the declaration line in Xcode.

Comment: I created the outlets through ctrl dragging. [Here](http://i.imgur.com/bMwz0kV.png) is the connection for my table view and [here](http://i.imgur.com/SIyUi43.png) is the connection for my image view. The connection exists, else I wouldn't be able to update the source of the table view.
As I mentioned above, it seems making calls to the view class that represents the connection between Xamarin.iOS and the xib file can only be done from the controller but I am not sure if this is true, calling the method from inside the table view source class doesn't work.

Comment: I'll agree, that's unexpected.